# Are the large and small creatures in Pitch Black the same species?

Tags: pitch-black

The un-named planet in "Pitch Black" was home to two different predatory species. Species A is a buzzard-sized creature that flies in a large swarm (think a swarm of flying pirahnas). Species B is much larger, about the size of a horse or cow. Species B can also fly, but apparently prefers to stay on the ground. Both species dwell underground during the planet's period of sun coverage, later emerging during the long eclipses.

Given that Species B was shown feeding on the smaller Species A, it leads me to believe that these are two different species - species that just so happen to share a similar body-structure and appearance. However, someone pointed out to me that the smaller ones are just immature versions of the big ones - apparently something mentioned by director David Twohy in an interview.

**Are the large and small creatures seen in Pitch Black different species altogether, or just different life-cycle variations of the same life-form?**

Comment: Eating the little ones would not preclude them from being the same species.

Comment: The wiki certainly thinks so; http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Bioraptor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The film's [shooting script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/pitch-black_shooting.html) is extremely clear that the largest creatures (later identified as [bio-raptors](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Bioraptor) in the commentary) are the adults, the intermediate creatures are adolescents and that the smallest creatures are mere hatchlings. **They're all the same species, and yes, they're happily cannibalistic**

> A NOISE from the supply room. Is it Ali? Just too scared to come out? Imam opens the door... And **hatchlings pour out.**
>
> Moving with a gang-intelligence, they circle the room in a wave, soar
> high into the rafters -- then plunge into the coring shaft, SQUEALS
> VANISHING to infinity. Shocked silence, then...

and

> RIDDICK'S POV: In degraded image, **we see the predators -- adult
> hatchlings** -- emerge from the spires. **They're large, mammalian,
> hammer-headed.** They CLICK with echo-location, sounding out the world
> they haven't inhabited in 60 years.

and

> RIDDICK'S POV: Of an adolescent predator. **It squats atop cargo, eating
> a hatchling.** A heavy bone-blade crowns its skull.